# How can I get the correct width of my form?

Tags: c#, winforms

When using the following code to get the size of a form and the position another form to the left of it the size of the form returned seems to be larger than it should be.

```
//form is the name of the second form that I'm trying to
//position to the left of this form
form.Left = this.Left - form.Width;
```

Back in the vb6 days I would use something like SaleWidth instead.  Is there something like that that I need to use in c#?  Or is this due to for shadows etc?  How can I get my second form to end up right next to the current form?

### Current Results

[image]

### Expected Results

[image]

Comment: `form.Left = this.Left - form.Width;`  *When* are you calling this?

Comment: In the `Form_Move` event of the current form.

Comment: The width property is the "client width" (i.e., the width of the client area of the form) I believe, and not the overall outer width of the form.  There's a way to figure this out by looking at all the properties, but I can't remember what that is.

Comment: The apparent gap between the forms is due to the window's theme.  The theme makes the form's non-client area border transparent.  If you make a call to the API method [SetWindowTheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/uxtheme/nf-uxtheme-setwindowtheme) to remove the theme, you will observe that your calculation is correct. i.e. `SetWindowTheme(this.Handle, " ", " ");`.  A hack is to adjust the width by: `(SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Width + SystemInformation.SizingBorderWidth)`.

Comment: @Flydog57 No, you have it the other way around.  ClientSize is the interior size, Width would be the overall width of the form, which is a fantasy number, since Windows lies about the overall width of a form due to those fancy border shades.

Comment: @PoulBak `Bounds.Width` gives the same results as `Size.Width` and `Form.Width`.

Comment: @TnTinMn I tried to use `form.Left = this.Left - form.Width - (SystemInformation.FrameBorderSize.Width + SystemInformation.SizingBorderWidth);` instead and I get the same results.  So no joy on that either.  `FrameBorderSize.Width` is 4 and `SizingBorderWidth` is 1.

Comment: You need to apply the offset for each form as you have two borders being made transparent.

Answer (score 2):

After a few tries with the comments others have made I found that the following will get me what I'm after.

```
form.Left = this.Left - (form.ClientRectangle.Width + SystemInformation.SizingBorderWidth);
```